# Break line in Genome Diagram biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I’m using Genome Diagram to display genomic informations. I would like to separate the feature name and its location by a break line. Then I do something like that :

```
gdFeature.add_feature(
    feat,
    color=red,
    sigil="ARROW",
    name=feat.qualifiers['product'][0].replace(" ", "_") + "\n" +
    str(feat.location.start) + " - " + str(feat.location.end),
    label_position="middle",
    label_angle=0,
    label=True)
```

gdFeature is an instance of Feature class (http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.Graphics.GenomeDiagram._Feature.Feature-class.html )

The problem is when I save my picture on PDF format, I got a black square instead of a break line :
[example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt4jo.jpg)

That’s not really what I want. Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dont' see a direct path. Biopython uses Reportlab to generate the pdf. In the GenomeDiagram the function `drawString` is called to write the name/label (function is [here](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/d8128ff166763dd8aaf68fb3f7e90c48b8ef68a1/src/reportlab/graphics/renderPDF.py?at=default)). I.e. when you pass a label like "First Line\nSecond Line", ReportLab generates the PDF code that resembles (numbers are made up):

```
BT /F1 48 Tf 1 0 0 1 210 400 Tm (First\nSecond)Tj ET
```

But that is not the way to print two lines in a PDF. You actually have to have two different lines of code, something like:

```
BT /F1 48 Tf 1 0 0 1 210 400 Tm (First)Tj ET
BT /F1 48 Tf 1 0 0 1 210 400 Tm (Second)Tj ET
```

And AFAIK, Biopython doesn't have it implemented.